# django_celert_resultsで生成されるテーブルの意味

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

## 環境

OS：Debian10/11
WEBサーバー：nginx
フレームワーク:Django
キューイング：celery
DB:postgreSQL
ブローカー:redis

celeryd,celerybeatがデーモン化されています。

## 目的

Debian10->11への移植

## 状況

django_celery_resultsでDBへの出力を行っています。
Debain11ではスケジュールされたタスクが機能していないようです。

データベーステーブルの状態を示します。
Debian11では、以下のテーブルが存在しています。
django_celery_results_chordcounter
django_celery_results_groupresult

これらのテーブルはいつ生成されて、どのような機能があるのでしょうか？
正しく機能していれば、実行後に消去されるテーブルでしょうか？

### Debian10

```bash
postgres=# \dt
                      List of relations
 Schema |               Name               | Type  |  Owner
--------+----------------------------------+-------+----------
 public | auth_group                       | table | postgres
 ...
 public | django_admin_log                 | table | postgres
 public | django_celery_results_taskresult | table | postgres
 public | django_content_type              | table | postgres
 public | django_migrations                | table | postgres
 public | django_session                   | table | postgres
 ...
```

### Debian11

```bash
postgres=# \dt
                      List of relations
 Schema |               Name                 | Type  |  Owner
--------+------------------------------------+-------+----------
 public | auth_group                         | table | postgres
 ...
 public | django_admin_log                   | table | postgres
 public | django_celery_results_chordcounter | table | postgres
 public | django_celery_results_groupresult  | table | postgres
 public | django_celery_results_taskresult   | table | postgres
 public | django_content_type                | table | postgres
 public | django_migrations                  | table | postgres
 public | django_session                     | table | postgres
 ...
```

## 補足情報

### ディレクトリツリー

```
./django
├── manage.py
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app_static
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── celeryconfig.py
│   ├── manager
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── api_urls.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── consumers.py
│   │   ├── debouce.py
│   │   ├── middleware.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py

│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── routing.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── setup_util.py
│   │   ├── tasks.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── throttle.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── routing.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates

│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── proxy


├── uwsgi
│   ├── django_app.ini
│   └── websocket.ini
```

### django project/settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'project.manager.apps.ManagerConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'channels',
    'django_celery_results',
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

### django project/celery.py

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('project')
app.config_from_object('project.celeryconfig')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

### django project/celeryconfig.py

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379'
accept_content = ['application/json']
task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo'

imports = (
    'project.manager.tasks',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

※あくまで「いつ生成されるか」に対してのみ回答します。

[ソースコードのリポジトリ](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results) を覗いてみると、[migrations](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/tree/main/django_celery_results/migrations) ディレクトリの下にあるファイルで作成されるように見えます。
`help_text=` で指定されている文字列が内容のヒントになりそうです。

[0008_chordcounter.py](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/blob/cb9448976bc51865922319c91b6c2218859ba80d/django_celery_results/migrations/0008_chordcounter.py#L24) (24行目)

> ```py
>                     help_text='Celery ID for the Chord header group',
> ```

[0009_groupresult.py](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/blob/cb9448976bc51865922319c91b6c2218859ba80d/django_celery_results/migrations/0009_groupresult.py#L37) (34行目)

> ```py
>                     help_text='Celery ID for the Group that was run',
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございます。Debian10、Debian11において、Python,Django,Celeryのバージョンも更新されており、質問内容のテーブルの作成有無はそこらへんの問題かもしれません。タスクが機能しないのは、Celeryグローバルオプションの扱い方がバージョンで改変されていたからでした。